# how to get data from JSON variable using a JSON type index

Tags: javascript, json

Given:

```
var data = {
  "AAA":[{"firstname":"john", "lastname":"Deo"},
         {"firstname":"Ann", "lastname":"Deo"}],
  "BBB":[{"name":"john", "age":19}, 
          "name":"jim", "age":21}] 
};

var a="AAA";
```

if I write this

```
  data.AAA[1].firstname
```

it works. But, how do i get the same result using `a` instead of `AAA`? like

```
data.a[1].firstname
```

which fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a variable that holds a key for you object (`a` in your case) you should use the square bracket syntax, like so:

```
data[a][1].firstname
```

Comment: if I want to do like this
$each(data[a],function(idx,entry){alert(entry.firstName);}) it does not work. How should i do?